# Having trouble installing... or even entering the OS

Tags: installation, 12.04

I recently got interested in Ubuntu and already read allot about it in the internet and a book i bought and decided to install it today.

I downloaded the version 12.04 64 bit and tried to install it by booting up the disc, but i couldn't even access the menu or anything because it would just crash, trying to show a menu.
I downloaded the 32 bit but same thing happened and searched for other alternatives. I installed it via alternative way (the one with a simple GUI) and it was successful but when i try to access the partition with the OS it still crashes right there.
I'm guessing its the video card and i search online and try different commands, but for some reason they are unsuccessful.

My PC Specs are:
Asus M4A89GTD-Pro

Phenom x4 unlocked 5 cores at 4GHZ

6Gb of Kingston Memory

AMD Radeon Hd 6790

If you need addition details please ask.

Im sorry if its a stupid question, i am new to the operating system and learning. Thank you for your support.

EDIT: here is the image I get every time it gets near a GUI when installing or alredy installed

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/85/img20120426222430.jpg/

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's your gfx card. Mine did the same thing for the longest time. Go to http://support.amd.com/us/Pages/AMDSupportHub.aspx get your driver, put it on a usb, reboot in recovery mode and try installing it from cli. If you need any help just ask (I'm a little busy at work right now or I would post more) Just make sure when you're done you run `update-initramfs -u -k all`

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and let you know if it worked

Answer (score 3):

when you try to boot into it your doing it from the grub boot menu, right? looks somewhat like this.
[image]

Comment: Yeah its got the grub boot menu but mine only has ubuntu, ubuntu (recovery) and windows 7

Comment: I guess if all else fails delete the partition and try again. Did you change your bios setting to boot from cd/dvd? you have to move cd/dvd to the top level, then you can boot from a disc. make sure your computer runs 64 or 32 bit. If you don't know how to boot into the bios google it for your specific computer.